# JavaScript SUM object values if the object's other values are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pretty new to JS high array methods and I have an array of objects that contain cost categories and value like this:

```
[{category: "Bars", amount: 31231},
{category: "Transport", amount: 1297},
{category: "Utilities", amount: 12300},
{category: "Bars", amount: 2000},
{category: "Transport", amount: 2500},
{category: "Education", amount: 21321}]
```

My goal is to reduce this array and sum the 'amount' values like this:

```
[{category: "Bars", amount: 33231},  //31231+2000
{category: "Transport", amount: 3797}, //1297+2500
{category: "Utilities", amount: 12300},
{category: "Education", amount: 21321}]
```

I tried reduce() and and forEach(), but I could not really find a way to solve the issue.
Thank you!

Comment: *"i tried ..."* please add this.

Comment: You can iterate thru the array and when categorys match add the amount to the first object and delete the latest one you found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `reduce` method to do it, so you will iterate over the array with items and for each item you will ask if that category don't exist into the `newObject` then initialize it with 0 value and then sum up the amount.

```js
var objects = [{category: "Bars", amount: 31231},
{category: "Transport", amount: 1297},
{category: "Utilities", amount: 12300},
{category: "Bars", amount: 2000},
{category: "Transport", amount: 2500},
{category: "Education", amount: 21321}];

var newObjectsMerged = objects.reduce((object, item) => {
  var category = item.category;
  var amount = item.amount;
  if (!object.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
    object[category] = 0;
  }
  
  object[category] += amount;
  return object;
}, {});

console.log("newObjectsMerged", newObjectsMerged);
```

Comment: Great and easy to follow solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by taking finc for the object and update or add a new array to the result set.

```js
var array = [{ category: "Bars", amount: 31231 }, { category: "Transport", amount: 1297 }, { category: "Utilities", amount: 12300 }, { category: "Bars", amount: 2000 }, { category: "Transport", amount: 2500 }, { category: "Education", amount: 21321 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { category, amount }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => o.category === category);
        if (temp) {
            temp.amount += amount;
        } else {
            r.push({ category, amount });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [{category: "Bars", amount: 31231},
{category: "Transport", amount: 1297},
{category: "Utilities", amount: 12300},
{category: "Bars", amount: 2000},
{category: "Transport", amount: 2500},
{category: "Education", amount: 21321}];


var itemsByName = items.reduce(function (map, item) {
  
  var summarizedItem = map.get(item.category);
  if (!summarizedItem) {
    summarizedItem = item;
  } else {
    summarizedItem.amount += item.amount;
  }
  
  map.set(item.category, summarizedItem);
  
  return map;
}, new Map());

console.log(Array.from(itemsByName.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var items = [{category: "Bars", amount: 31231},
{category: "Transport", amount: 1297},
{category: "Utilities", amount: 12300},
{category: "Bars", amount: 2000},
{category: "Transport", amount: 2500},
{category: "Education", amount: 21321}];

// get all categories names
var categories = items.map(item => item.category).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

// create a new object with sum of amounts
var result = categories.map(item => { 
  return { 
     category: item, 
     amount: items.filter(c => c.category === item).reduce((accum, curr) => accum + curr.amount, 0) 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A short ES6 version with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const data = [{category: "Bars", amount: 31231},{category: "Transport", amount: 1297},{category: "Utilities", amount: 12300},{category: "Bars", amount: 2000},{category: "Transport", amount: 2500},{category: "Education", amount: 21321}];

const grouped = data.reduce((all, {category: c, amount: a}) =>
    ({...all, [c]: (all[c] || 0) + a }), {});

const result = Object.keys(grouped).map(k => ({category: k,amount: grouped[k] }));

console.log(result);
```